# Lightning "Set Component Visibility" Feature Not working as expected

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I have two lightning components and I am trying to show the lightning component on the record page depending on the Record Type on Case Object instead of creating the lightning page for each record type separately . So I placed the two components on the Lightning Pages and have the Set Component Visibility setup like below. I showed the rule I have on each lightning component on the same page

[image]

[image]

The issue is when I open the Case Record of Record Type TIS it shows the 1st component, but when the record type of Customer Service is opened no com[ponent show up. Can anyone tell me what I am missing here

Comment: Have you tried `Customer_Service`? I think it might want the developer name, not the actual name.

Comment: Awesome that fixed the issue. I have struggling last 1 hour. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Developer Name" for the record type. The developer name defaults to the same as the normal name, but has the following rules: (a) it can only start with a letter, (b) it can only use A-Z, 0-9, and _, (c) it cannot start or end with _, and (d) it cannot have more than one consecutive _.

In this case, you should use "Customer_Service" as the record type name. You can check the Developer Name in Setup > Object Manager > Object > Record Types.